# Creating URL based on an API key in OSRMRoadManager

Tags: java, android, kotlin, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I've signed up for an API on openrouteservice.org. How do I import it into OSRMRoadManager? I've tried all the combinations from the examples on their [website](https://openrouteservice.org/dev/#/api-docs/v2/directions/%7Bprofile%7D/get), but my every try results in the 403 error with a comment `org.json.JSONException: No value for code` and a link to the following:

```
{
  "error": "Daily quota reached or API key unauthorized"
}
```

(I haven't used that API before, so I couldn't have used up the quota. The key is valid, as I have tested it with the links from the aforementioned website)

My Kotlin code (in my most recent attempt) is as following ([MY_API_KEY] is obviously replacing my real key):

```
    val roadManager = OSRMRoadManager(context, context?.packageName)
    (roadManager as OSRMRoadManager).setService("https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car/geojson?api_key=[MY_API_KEY]")
    val waypoints = ArrayList<GeoPoint>()
    waypoints.add(GeoPoint(lastLocLat, lastLocLong)) //last known location
    val endPoint = GeoPoint(randomOverlay.getItem(0).point.latitude, randomOverlay.getItem(0).point.longitude) //destination
    waypoints.add(endPoint)
    val road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints)
```

My guess is that the waypoint coordinates should be included differently in the link, but I don't know how to alter that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openrouteservice directions format is not identical to OSRM, so you cannot use OSRMRoadManager.
If you really - really - want to use openrouteservice, you will have to develop corresponding openrouteserviceRoadManager.

Alternative: use one among the 3 routing services already accessible with OBP. Pros and cons [here](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/WhichRoutingService).

Comment: Ohh, for some reason I thought they were the same. I've switched to MapQuest, thank you for your answer.